# Macbook is lagging and freezing when connected to WiFi

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

Everything was working fine and suddenly I am facing my MacBook is lagging and apps keep on bouncing in the dock when I try to open them.

I tried resetting SMC, NVRAM/PRAM but the problem still exists. I tried restarting shut it down for sometimes but no luck.

I turned off WiFi and everything was working fine, no lag and no freeze but as I turned WiFi on, it started lagging again.

Any ideas what's causing this issue?

Comment: Something is obviously happening when you connect to a network.   Do you have an Ethernet adapter to connect to the network with? This will help rule out hardware vs. software.  Also, boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to see if the problem persists.  This will tell us if a 3rd party piece of sofware is being loaded that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Allan, I don't have any Ethernet adapter connected. I boot in the safe mode for the first time, it looks like the problem persists. I am not using any third-party services which use a heavy internet bandwidth. A simple program like VLC media player is not opening on a single click, It keeps on bouncing and as I disconnects the internet it opens suddenly.

Followed this thread but it didn't' worked out for me https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389062/macbook-is-lagging-and-freezing-when-connected-to-wifi?noredirect=1#comment532009_389062

Comment: I can replicate the request. I am sure this is not the problem with the hardware as if the WiFi is turned on and as long as I am not connected to the WiFi network, it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem was with my network cache. None of the online help worked for me.

The problem was occurring only for my home WiFi. I connect with the VPN and noticed everything was working smoothly as earlier.

I cleared my DNS cache, and reset the network configurations. I deleted the directory `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` and run the commands to flush the DNS cache

```bsh
$ sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Make sure to take the backup of the `SystemConfiguration` just incase. Your system can generate the files later.

Hopefully, this will help anyone else who seems to be having freezing issues when connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, thank you Muhaddis. Wanted to add that I also needed to disable SIP in Mojave in order to delete the SystemConfiguration folder.